# an unexpected error has occurred when attempting to reserve the app name

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to share the desktop application I made on C# in the microsoft market, but when I try to install it through the microsoft developer dashboard, it says that it is not complete even though I fill in the packages and I cannot publish my application. No matter what I type in the name reservation via visual studio, I get the error "an unexpected error has occurred when attempting to reserve the app name"

[image]